# Select statement inside loop returns more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Hi i'm new to psl/sql but i have few knowlege on sql.
I'm trying put a select statement inside a loop.
Base on my research i need a storage for the output of my select but the output of my select statement returns more than one row.

How can i store multiple row on my storege?

Here's my attemp.

```
DECLARE
  vCAR_NO          IQA_CAR.CAR_NO%TYPE;
  vISSUEDTO             IQA_CAR.ISSUEDTO%TYPE;

begin 

FOR cur_rec in (Select Distinct ISSUEDTO,ISSUEDDATE from IQA_CAR where to_char( ISSUEDDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') < to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD') and CLOSEDDATE is null order by ISSUEDDATE DESC, ISSUEDTO)
LOOP
     Select CAR_NO,ISSUEDTO
     into vCAR_NO,vISSUEDTO
      from IQA_CAR where to_char( TARGET_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') < to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD') and CLOSEDDATE is null and ISSUEDTO = cur_rec.ISSUEDTO  order by TARGET_DATE DESC, ISSUEDTO;

END LOOP;

end;
/
```

The reason for this is to get all CAR_NO per ISSUEDTO and send email all CAR_NO  per ISSUEDTO

Hope someone help me out with this.
Than you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle is very careful about variable assignments.  I am guessing that you want the top row from the final `order by`.  You can do this using aggregation and the `keep` syntax:

```
 Select max(CAR_NO) keep (dense_rank first order by TARGET_DATE DESC, ISSUEDTO),
        max(ISSUEDTO) keep (dense_rank first order by TARGET_DATE DESC, ISSUEDTO)
 into vCAR_NO, vISSUEDTO
 from IQA_CAR
 where to_char( TARGET_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') < to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD') and
       CLOSEDDATE is null and
       ISSUEDTO = cur_rec.ISSUEDTO;
```

Alternatively, you can use a subquery:

```
 Select CAR_NO,ISSUEDTO
 into vCAR_NO,vISSUEDTO
 from (select c.*
       from IQA_CAR c
       where to_char( TARGET_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') < to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') and
              CLOSEDDATE is null and
              ISSUEDTO = cur_rec.ISSUEDTO 
       order by TARGET_DATE DESC, ISSUEDTO
      ) c
 where rownum = 1;
```

Comment: The reason for this is to get all CAR_NO per ISSUEDTO and send email all CAR_NO per ISSUEDTO.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send all car_no to the issuedto then you can send comma separated list of all `car_no` using `LISTAGG`.

You need to change the query as folloing:

```
Select LISTAGG(CAR_NO, ' ,') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TARGET_DATE DESC),
       ISSUEDTO
     into vCAR_NO,vISSUEDTO
      from IQA_CAR where to_char( TARGET_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') < to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD') and CLOSEDDATE is null and ISSUEDTO = cur_rec.ISSUEDTO  
GROUP BY ISSUEDTO;
```

Make sure to change the data type of the variable `vCAR_NO` to `VARCHAR2`.

This will generate one recird per `ISSUEDTO` with all `CAR_NO` as comma-separated.

Cheers!!